# Teradata SQL - case when and logic to show milestones

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table with three columns and want to create 'milestones' column with the below logic. Note the MILESTONE is the desired result.

Rules are - status READY for 'DAYS TO GO' >= 14 for TYPE A is ON TRACK
- status READY for 'DAYS TO GO' >= 30 for TYPE B is ON TRACK

```
STATUS  DAYS TO GO  TYPE    MILESTONE
READY   13          A   ON TRACK
OPEN    15          A   ON TRACK
READY   15          A   ON TRACK
OPEN    13          A   LATE
READY   28          B   ON TRACK
OPEN    31          B   ON TRACK
OPEN    29          B   LATE
OPEN    33          B   ON TRACK
```

My issue is that CASE WHEN do not pick up correct then is more then 30, and is READY.

```
    CASE 
WHEN TYPE = 'A' AND STATUS = 'READY' AND DAYS TO GO >= 14 THEN 'ON TRACK'

WHEN TYPE = 'B' AND STATUS = 'READY' AND DAYS TO GO >= 30 THEN 'ON TRACK 

ELSE 'LATE' END
```

Comment: The code fragment you pasted at the end of your question won't even run.  Can you include the full actual query?

Comment: I need a help with logic and not the code.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, but readers of your question want to see some sample data, a query, the expected output, and then maybe a description of what you think is wrong.  You haven't given us this information.

Comment: Afraid I agree with Tim; this code sample has blatant syntax errors and cannot possibly have been copied from a working query. No database system in the world will take a set of inputs `(type,status,days)` of `(A,READY,13)` and apply a logic where `TYPE = 'A' AND STATUS = 'READY' AND DAYS TO GO >= 14` is true unless there is some data typing idiosyncrasy, the 13 is stored as a string and the number 14 is being interpreted as an ascii code for some low-ascii character (in which case the '13' really is greater than CHR(14))

Comment: @CaiusJard No reason to fear agreeing with me `;-)` ... some people even report liking it.

Comment: Rules and expected result don't match.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon thanks to @Tim Biegeleisen I was able to anser my own question. It looks like i needed to include all rules into CASE WHEN.

So my data is (I moved to mySQL as it was the simplest thing to do)

```
CREATE TABLE tableA
(

STATUS VARCHAR (5),
DAYS int (2),
TYPE VARCHAR (2)) ;

    insert into tableA values 
    ("READY",13,"A"),
    ("OPEN",15,"A"),
    ("READY",15,"A"),
    ("OPEN",13,"A"),
    ("READY",28,"B"),
    ("OPEN",31,"B"),
    ("OPEN",29,"B"),
    ("OPEN",33,"B");
```

My select is:

```
SELECT t.STATUS,t.DAYS,t.TYPE,

CASE
    WHEN (t.TYPE = "A" AND t.DAYS >= 14 AND t.STATUS = "READY") THEN "ON TRACK" 
    WHEN (t.TYPE = "A" AND t.DAYS <= 14 AND t.STATUS = "READY") THEN "ON TRACK" 
    WHEN (t.TYPE = "A" AND t.DAYS >= 14 AND t.STATUS <> "READY") THEN "ON TRACK" 

    WHEN (t.TYPE = "B" AND t.DAYS >= 30 AND t.STATUS = "READY") THEN "ON TRACK" 
    WHEN (t.TYPE = "B" AND t.DAYS <= 30 AND t.STATUS = "READY") THEN "ON TRACK" 
    WHEN (t.TYPE = "B" AND t.DAYS >= 30 AND t.STATUS <> "READY") THEN "ON TRACK" 

ELSE "LATE" END AS "MILESTONE"

FROM tableA t;
```

Comment: This can be rewritten as `CASE
    WHEN (t.TYPE = "A" AND t.Days < 14 AND t.STATUS <> "READY")
      OR (t.TYPE = "B" AND t.Days < 30 AND t.STATUS <> "READY") THEN "LATE" 
    ELSE "ON TRACK" 
END AS "MILESTONE"`